# Is it possible to generate PDFs of the entire scrollable web page?

Tags: mac, google-chrome, firefox, pdf

I am trying to capture my transcript from a webpage but there is no feature to capture all contents of the transcript. So I'm looking for a tool that can help save the entire webpage as a multi-page PDF rather than cutting it off after 1 page. So a webpage with a lot of content that requires scrolling down should be captured in multiple PDF pages.

Comment: For such a situation, Acrobat's WebCapture function does exactly that. (normally, I try to do the other way; make the default page big enough that a single webpage will get onto a single PDF page…)

Answer (score 0):

By default (on Chrome at least) you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and change the printer to “Save as PDF.”

If this doesn't work you'll want to install a PDF Writer installed to handle to 'printing' to PDF. I've always used a small, free simple one called [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/).

Install this, it should install drivers and appear as a printer.

Following the same steps as above, select CutePDF as the printer and that should scale the website into a PDF.

Comment: I am aware of the `ctrl+p` feature but my concern is that this feature does not save the web page into a multi-page pdf. For example, if you go to Yahoo.com, you will notice that you can scroll down. If you wanted to capture the entire homepage into multiple pages, you can't use that feature to get it done.

Comment: @btrballin I've just tried this on the 'Newest' questions page of this forum. This has made a 2-page PDF file which contains the full contents of the website. What do you mean by multi-page PDF? Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I think this website is more "modern" so it allows us to print all the contents of a scrollable web page here, but it doesn't work for the website where I can view my transcript.

Comment: The browser is what controls this particular function. Not the compatibility of the website. Can you give me an example to investigate?

Comment: Is it possible that the content of your transcript is in a frame? I've noticed a lot of educational sites do this. For some unknown reason, Chrome doesn't include "this frame" options by default. Maybe try this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/print-this-frame/bamldpmhndfcingobhmkholjnkioglob?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You can select the text you want and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select printer **Save as PDF**. This way it will show more than one page, but will cut some headers and side bars that are locking the print in one page.

Some sites are correctly configured to show the important part so it shows more pages with all the content when you print it.